# How to set RecyclerView in android widget

Tags: java, android, view, widget, android-recyclerview

From : https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

I want to set `RecyclerView` in widget on home screen. Is it possible, and if it is, how to do it? Give some samples please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView in Android Home Screen Widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051733/recyclerview-in-android-home-screen-widget)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

RecyclerView is not supported to be used as a RemoteView. See [CreatingLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout)

> A RemoteViews object (and, consequently, an App Widget) can support
>   the following layout classes:
>
> FrameLayout
>   LinearLayout
>   RelativeLayout
>   GridLayout
>
> And the following widget classes:
>   AnalogClock
>   Button
>   Chronometer
>   ImageButton
>   ImageView
>   ProgressBar
>   TextView
>   ViewFlipper
>   ListView
>   GridView
>   StackView
>   AdapterViewFlipper

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem, i'll try.

Answer (score 9):

`RecyclerView` is [not presently supported for app widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).