# RecyclerView in Android Home Screen Widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-recyclerview, homescreen

Is there a way to put a recyclerview in an android homescreen widget. If so, how would you set the adapter and layout manager.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set RecyclerView in android widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939152/how-to-set-recyclerview-in-android-widget)

Answer (score 3):

No, sorry, at the present time, `RecyclerView` is not one of the supported widgets for an app widget.